# How to join a collection with a query

Tags: collection, grid, export, join, renderer

I have a table represented in backend with two rendered fields, but when I try to make a CSV export from this grid, those two fields are not included.

So I tried to make a join from the initial collection but I would have to make a join with a query / select like this:

```
SELECT main_table.*, art.artworks_uploaded
FROM mage_artist_details AS main_table
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT artist_id, COUNT(*) AS artworks_uploaded
        FROM mage_art_works
        GROUP BY artist_id
    ) AS art
    ON main_table.user_id = art.artist_id
```

Any ideas of how can I obtain this?

If I try and use directly this query for my collection, I lose pagination in grid.

If I try and replace a table with a query in the next line I get errors:

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(
    array('art' => 'mage_art_works'),
    'main_table.user_id = art.artist_id',
    array('artworks_uploaded' => 'COUNT(*)')
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Create Virtual Query

Create ZEND SQL query which is give you `artworks_uploaded` basic of `artist_id`,which give an virtual result query with count and artist id.

```
$ReadAdapter=Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
        $select = $ReadAdapter()->select()
            ->from('mage_art_works', array())
            ->columns(array('artist_id',
    'artworks_uploaded' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*)'))
    )->group('mage_art_works.artist_id');
```

### Alias table using above result:

then add the below ZEND SQL to the alias table

```
$collection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
        array('art' => new Zend_Db_Expr(" ( $select ) ")),
        'main_table.user_id = art.artist_id',
        array()
    );
```

Comment: $ReadAdapter = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
        $select = $ReadAdapter->select()
                ->from('mage_art_works', array())
                ->columns(array(
                            'artist_id',
                            'artworks_uploaded' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*)')
                        ))
                ->group('mage_art_works.artist_id');

Comment: $collection->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(
                array('art' => $select),//new Zend_Db_Expr($ReadAdapter)),
                'main_table.user_id = art.artist_id',
                array('artworks_uploaded')
            );

Comment: there were some errors and in my comments is the final solution. if you edit your answer, I will gladly accept it

Comment: It would be fair for everyone to get a bug free solution

Comment: what  is the issue  and please let m know

Comment: $ReadAdapter() is not a function

Comment: ->columns need to be ->columns(array(....))

Comment: array('art' => new Zend_Db_Expr($ReadAdapter)) is array('art' => $select),

Comment: please .. i have done all the thing on concept.not testing .

Comment: it will work only when you add parentheses for the $select :
new Zend_Db_Expr(" **(** $select **)** ")